# htaccess and GET for subpages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do sorting passing get value in htaccess to php:

I have sth like:

RewriteRule ^pubs$ pubs.php
RewriteRule ^pubs/beer$ pubs.php?sort=beer

Above code is working fine. Now Im trying to do the same thing for subpages (cities):

```
RewriteRule ^pubs/(.*)$ district.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^pubs/(.*)/beer$ district.php?name=$1&sort=beer
```

The links look like:
www.domain.com/pubs/beer - working ok
www.domain.com/pubs/new-york/beer - not working

What I'm doing wrong? If i delete line *RewriteRule ^pubs/(.*)$ district.php?name=$1* then the link www.domain.com/pubs/new-york/beer is working. I spend hours to find solution with no luck. I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i delete line RewriteRule ^pubs/(.*)$ district.php?name=$1 then the
>   link www.domain.com/pubs/new-york/beer is working.

because www.domain.com/pubs/new-york/beer is matching by

```
RewriteRule ^pubs/(.*)$ district.php?name=$1
```

resulting in district.php?name=newyork/beer instead of matching

```
RewriteRule ^pubs/(.*)/beer$ district.php?name=$1&sort=beer
```

one way you could fix this would be:

```
RewriteRule ^pubs/([^/]*)$ district.php?name=$1
```

so if there is an additional slash anywhere after your city the rule will be ignored and proceed to the 2nd rule... just be sure to put it after

```
RewriteRule ^pubs/beer$ pubs.php?sort=beer
```

or it will match beer as if it were a city name like district.php?name=beer

Comment: no problem. If you have trouble understanding why a rewrite isn't working, add [R=302] to the end so it will actually redirect the url and you can see if its going to a wrong url (incorrect redirection or interference by another rule) or not rewriting at all (incorrect pattern matching, rule not being applied)